# Dynamic php website using CODEIGNITER

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, dynamic, phpmyadmin

My problem is that I have made a PHP page .

It has a button of "add company" that according to my employer should create a table (in database) of a the company with the desired name and also another PHP page should be automatically made that displays the table of that company from the database.

ALL this should be done on click of the add company button.

Comment: do you know the code that i should write in model and controller of  the codeigniter file??

Answer (score 0):

Have search your similiar question in here?? or have you search that on google??

Maybe this link would help,
[Bulit Data Grid with Codeigniter](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-ajax-data-grids-with-codeigniter-and-jquery--net-22004)

If you new to php and codeigniter you have to search a lot case here or googling, and don't forget to describe the issue, error notice, or whatever you think the code is wrong you must describe it detail.

Hope this help :-)